# How java Big Decimal holds precision

Tags: java, bigdecimal

i am subtracting one bigdecimal from another. bellow is the code.

```
BigDecimal s=new BigDecimal(new BigDecimal("472.24").floatValue() - new BigDecimal("100.0").floatValue());
System.out.println(s);
```

Expected Answer is = `372.24`

Actual Answer = `372.239990234375`

can anyone please explain the reason and solution to get expected answer in BigDecimal

Comment: You are using BigDecimal wrong. Don't convert to floats but instead use the methods subtract() to subtract two BigDecimals. When you convert back to float you are giving up all advantages of the BigDecimal class and might as well not use them at all.

Comment: You are not subtracting BigDecimals. You are subtracting `float` values instead - because you are getting each of the BigDecimals as a `float` before you are doing the computation.

Comment: I wonder why those downvotes. This can be bad code, but it's still a very valid question, as it involves (bad) number conversion and float point precission.

Comment: @Shirkam: I didn't downvote, but, well, the question is not correct. As others have noted, the code does not subtract two BigDecimals, it subtracts two floats. So the question is actually not valid, IMO.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Strictly talking, you are right. The title of the question, the question itself, and answers, do not match, because there is a misconcept there.

Answer (score 5):

Why not using `.subtract`:

```
BigDecimal s = new BigDecimal("472.24");
BigDecimal result = s.subtract(new BigDecimal("100.0"));
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output**

```
372.24
```

Answer (score 3):

No. You are **not** subtracting to BigDecimal values. You are subtracting two **float** values - and there completely different "rules" apply.

You have to use the built-in [subtract()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#subtract(java.math.BigDecimal)) method in order to **subtract** those BigDecimal objects!

That is all there is to this.

Answer (score 1):

You shall subtract them like that:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("472.24").subtract(new BigDecimal("100.0")));
```

Comment: Did you mean "subtract"?